# HX711 ADC Simultaneous data reading from both channels

Tags: circuit-analysis, adc, analog, analysis

I am trying to connect **two** load cells to raspberry pi 3 using HX711 24-bit ADC.
I was wondering if we can get the output from **two** channels simultaneously i.e A and B  .
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if we can get the output from two channels
>   simultaneously

No you can't: -

[image]

Input A and input B are selected using a multiplexer therefore simulatanous analogue conversion is impossible. You will have to read the data sheet to see what the minimum time period is between reads but it won't be zero.